# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, connection, port

i'm running this script on python:

```
import requests
url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

and i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /quote/AAPL?p=AAPL (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcbf36d3a20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

what could be the reason?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `https` instead?

Comment: yes, i got the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me so I'm unsure. However if getting data from yahoo finance, try the api instead which will save you parsing the data.

http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/

Is it just the yahoo site that requests won't get or is it a general error?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your url http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/ but it didn't help, i tried another url site but i encountered the same error.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, what type of set up you have, you need to give more information otherwise everything is purely guess work.

Comment: Think about the problem you are having and what details you can pull out of your situation that might be useful. Since you're working with python and requests which version do these both have. This problem also has to do with networking since requests in some way can't access the internet. So do you have a firewall that might be blocking the connection. Are you able to access websites through other means, i.e. your browser..... have a think. Have you tried anything if yes what did you do and what happened, if not why not....